# Quick way to set custom syntax highlighting in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting, springsource

I know I'm not the first to need this. I am working on an in house created codebase and I would like to apply highlighting to it within Eclipse. In Notepad++ I can set language for the file I'm looking at. Is there any way to do this for Eclipse?

The code I'm working on would use the same syntax styling as C++.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your best bet is to go to Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File associations.  Add the file extension of the thing you are trying to open and add the C++ editor as the associated default editor.

If there is no file extension, then things are a little harder.  Instead of double-clicking to open the file, right-click -> Open with... -> other -> C++ editor.  This will remember your choice for that file only.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried this before but no highlighting was applied. I noticed that in order for it to work you have to have the color editor first in the list of editors for the extension.

I do notice some of the syntax coloring is still different however. Is there a way to set custom colors? or change the colors used?

Comment: I don't know much about CDT, but I would imagine that there's something like the functionality that you get for JDT.  Ie, Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> syntax coloring.

Answer (score 1):

As [Andrew Eisenberg said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10843530/4561887), go to <kbd>Window</kbd> --> <kbd>Preferences</kbd> --> <kbd>General</kbd> --> <kbd>Editors</kbd> --> <kbd>File Associations</kbd> and ensure your choices for editor for each file type are correct according to your desires.

However, for Eclipse CDT most of your file types are set in <kbd>Preferences</kbd> --> <kbd>C/C++</kbd> --> <kbd>File Types</kbd> instead.

Also, like he said, you can use the right-click menu to choose your own editor, including an external system editor, such as Sublime Text 3, Atom, Visual Studio Code, Notepad++, etc.
<kbd>Right click on the file</kbd> --> <kbd>Open With</kbd> --> <kbd>Other...</kbd> --> choose an "Internal editor" or "External program" to your liking, optionally checking the box at the bottom to make this the default choice next time.